# MS Access 2003: Date pickers question

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I created an application using MS Access 2007 that utilizes Date pickers (among other functionalities). I then saved it as Access 2003 db, but I was reported that date pickers aren't working.

Now, I'm changing other issues I found there, but I read somewhere (google search) that MS Access doesn't support Date pickers, and that one must install something additionally in order to support date pickers. If this isn't an option, do I have any other way of enabling date pickers?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distribute the date picker control with the .mdb file

Comment: oh... that sounds complicated :)... it's a long story.
but thx for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use [Stephen Lebans' date picker](http://www.lebans.com/monthcalendar.htm). I've used it and it works fine, though it is somewhat old-fashioned-looking.

Comment: thank you for your answer. however, i turned to non-programmer's way: i persuaded people who will be using it that it's simpler that way :)

Comment: What was your solution? It might be helpful to others to hear about it. You accepted the answer of distributing the calendar OCX with your app, but that's not simpler for the end users than the Stephen Lebans date picker, which requires nothing installed on the target workstation to use.

Comment: no, the thing was that your answer came late. i was looking for a simple solution, but found out that i could avoid the solution totally.

Comment: So, what solution did you use to avoid the problem? Others might benefit from knowing what you ended up doing.